Consecutive binary block in MIP modeling with variable length
I'm currently modeling a MIP and face a problem on how to tackle consecutive binarys.
I have a integer variable $A_v$ which marks the start time and a integer processing time $P_v$. I want to model MIP constraints that set the binary variable $X_{t,v}$ and the next $P_v$ binary variables to one, if t= $A_v$. Example: $A_{v1}$ = 5, $P_{v1}$ = 2 then:
$X_{1,v1}$ = 0,
$X_{2,v1}$ = 0,
$X_{3,v1}$ = 0,
$X_{4,v1}$ = 0,
$X_{5,v1}$ = 1,
$X_{6,v1}$ = 1,
$X_{7,v1}$ = 1,
$X_{8,v1}$ = 0 ...
Thoughts:
I can define a start time binary variable $E_{t,v}$ and a end time binary variable $L_{t,v}$ and set all entries of $X_{t, v}$ in between and including them to one. The problem is that this requires three variables to be introduced. The advantage is that this approach is relatively easy to understand.
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{tmax} t * E_{t,v} = A_v \forall v
$$
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{tmax} t * L_{t,v} = A_v + P_v \forall v
$$
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{tmax} E_{t,v} = 1 \forall v
$$
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{tmax} L_{t,v} = 1 \forall v
$$
$$
X_{t,v} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{t} E_{t,v} \forall t, v
$$
$$
X_{t,v} \leq 1- \sum_{k=1}^{t-1} L_{t,v} \forall t \geq 2, v
$$
$$
X_{t,v} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{t} E_{t,v} + \sum_{k=t}^{tmax} L_{t,v} - 1 \forall t, v
$$
I am stuck at how to simplify this equation system. Is it possible to omit the $L_{t,v}$ and use the processing time directly to declare the $X_{t,v}$? Is there maybe even a formulation or approach that one can use with a variable in the indices like $$X_{t \leq tt \leq t+P_v,v} \geq E_{t,v} \forall t,v$$
I thank you for taking the time to read the question and would appreciate any help, corrections or ideas. I would also appreciate resources to learn if you have them - I am far from an expert in this.

For simplicity, I'll omit the $v$ index.  You want to enforce $X_t=1 \iff A \le t \le A+P$.  You can do so as follows, without introducing additional variables:
\begin{align}
A - t &\le (t_\max-t)(1 - X_t) &&\text{for all $t$}\\
t - (A+P) &\le t(1 - X_t) &&\text{for all $t$}\\
\sum_t X_t &= P+1
\end{align}
